# Create an Access Query to see if in another field?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am creating queries for my database, and I want to know if the Artist_Name Field Value (A string) is part of a field in a different table, Band. I want to see if the Artist_Name is in the Band_Members field. Both are short text fields. I am using the Design View to create this query, which I will later edit in SQL. I will attach an Image to show my Query Relationships and Fields: [Query Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zfBP.png)

Comment: Like you have for Songs, you should have a junction table for Bands, as artists can move around, work solo, or with several bands.

Comment: Imagine that artists cannot move around from band to band. The Band Members field is just a text field, with the band members names separated by commas. I just want to see if Artist_Name is a substring of Band_Members in this query. Also, it is too late at this point to introduce another Junction Table.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `DCount` function to count the number of records in `Band` having `Band_Members` equal to `Artist_Name`.
2. You can create a left join from `Artist` table to `Band` table, on fields `Artist_Name` and `Band_Members`, but note that it may blow up the number of records in your output if artists are part of multiple bands.

I don't understand the field `Band.Band_Members` though; I suppose there is some one-to-may relationship between a band and it's members.

Comment: Hi GWR, The field Band.Band_Members is a short text field, with the band members names separated by a comma. As you can see in my attached picture, my relationships are already set, and I don't really want to change them. I want a query to see if Artist.Artist_Name is a substring of Band.Band_Members.

Comment: Then you can use Instr function in the dcount solution or in the join: instr(Band.Band_Members, Artist.Artist_Name) > 0. But really you are better off changing your database design.